# Nilpotent action on $p$-group

Tags: finite-groups, algebraic-number-theory, abelian-groups, topological-groups, p-adic-number-theory

Let $A$ be a finite, abelian $p$-group and $\Gamma$ is a multiplicative topological group isomorphic with the additive group of $p$−adic integers $\mathbb Z_p.$ and let $\gamma_0$ a topological generator of $\Gamma.$ Suppose that $\Gamma$ acts continuously  by multiplication by $\gamma_0.$ $$(a,\gamma_0)\longrightarrow \gamma_0.a.$$

How to prove that $T=1-\gamma_0$  acts nilpotently on $A $ (i.e:if $a\in A$ then $T^{n_0}a = 0$ for $n_0\in \mathbb N^*.$) ?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Are you writing the action of $\;\Gamma\;$ additively? What is then $\;\gamma_0-1\in\Gamma\;$ ? Is $\;\Gamma\;$ abelian?

Comment: @DonAntonio; Yes $\Gamma$ is abelian, this notations used in Iwasawa theory.

Comment: You may want to mention that in your question, @user44319... and perhaps ask the question in overflow.

Comment: @DonAntonio; $\Gamma$ is a multiplicative topological group isomorphic with the additive group of $p$−adic integers $\mathbb Z_p.$

Comment: I see, @user44319...but then the $\;\gamma_0-1\;$ means you in fact do *not* use this group's action on $\;A\;$ but rather the group ring $\;F[\Gamma]\;,\;\;F\;$ some ring/field? Otherwise I can't understand how to "add"$\;\gamma_0\;$ and $\;1\;$ if the group's action multiplicative.

Comment: @DonAntonio, yes exactly right.

Comment: Ok, @user44319 . Thanks. My knowledge of Iwasawa theory reduces to *guessing* Iwasawa was japanese...and it had a rather important role in proving Fermat's Last Theorem.

Comment: @DonAntonio; you're welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a \in A$. $A$ carries the discrete topology, so the singleton set $\{a\}$ is open in $A$.

Since the action map $\alpha : \Gamma \times A \to A$ is continuous, $\alpha^{-1}(\{a\})$ is open in $\Gamma \times A$.

So $\alpha^{-1}(\{a\}) \cap ( \Gamma \times \{a\} ) = \{(\gamma,a) \in \Gamma \times A : \gamma \cdot a = a\}$ is open in $\Gamma \times \{a\}$.

Thus the stabiliser of $a$ is an open subgroup of $\Gamma$, and therefore has finite index in $\Gamma$. Since $\Gamma$ is pro-$p$, this index is a power of $p$; say $p^n$.

Thus $\gamma_0^{p^n} \cdot a = a$. So $( (1 + T)^{p^n} - 1 )\cdot a = 0$. Since $(1 + T)^{p^n} \equiv 1 + T^{p^n} \mod p$, we get $T^{p^n} \cdot a \in pA$. This is true for all $a \in A$ and $A$ is finite, so in fact $T^{p^m} \cdot A \subseteq pA$ for some $m$.

So $T^{2p^m} \cdot A \subseteq T^{p^m} \cdot pA = p T^{p^m} \cdot A \subseteq p^2 A$ and similarly $T^{ip^m} \cdot A \subseteq p^iA$ for all $i \geq 0$. But $A$ is a finite abelian $p$-group so $p^i A = 0$ for some $i$. Hence $T^{p^m i} \cdot A = 0$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.